# Is HTTPContext obsolete in WCF?

Tags: wcf

HTTPContext is always null in my WCF calls, is it obsolete or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you Marc, will have a look

Comment: See my response to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519690/how-to-debug-a-wcf-service-with-an-http-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular HTTPContext is no longer used with WCF. You want the instance context.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    InstanceContext ic = OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext;
}
```

See this link for more details

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/23/understanding-instancecontext-in-wcf/

You can also enable [compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) so your WCF service acts like an old webservice, but you are better off using the InstanceContext

Comment: Link to the blog is down and Google does not seem to have it cached.

Answer (score 1):

t attribute for your service:

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

and add

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

option into web.config "system.serviceModel" section.